# Jackson registerSubtypes not working in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, jackson2

I was trying to use the `registerSubtypes` function from `Jackson` following [this tutorial](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/02/01/polymorphism-with-jackson/).

So I've converted this code into `Kotlin` like so:

```
interface Vehicle {
    val name: String
}
class Car @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty("name") override val name: String) : Vehicle
class Truck @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty("name") override val name: String) : Vehicle

class Vehicles @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty("vehicles") var vehicles: List<Vehicle>)

fun main() {
    val MAPPER = jacksonObjectMapper()
    MAPPER.registerSubtypes(NamedType(Truck::class.java, "Truck"))
    MAPPER.registerSubtypes(NamedType(Car::class.java, "Car"))

    val vehicles = Vehicles(listOf(Car("Dodge"), Truck("Scania")))
    val json = MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(vehicles)
    println(json)
}
```

But the output result is the following:

```
{
  "vehicles" : [ {
    "name" : "Dodge"
  }, {
    "name" : "Scania"
  } ]
}
```

It doesn't contain the `"@type"` field, so deserialization doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix it?

Jackson Kotlin version: `2.9.6`

Answer (score 1):

It is not related with `Kotlin`. Linked article uses `Jackson` in version `2.9.3`. But a little bit later [`Another two gadgets to exploit default typing issue in jackson-databind (CVE-2018-5968)`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1899) bug appeared and `Jackson` had to fixed that. In [`Jackson Release 2.9.4`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.4) this bug was fixed. Later on, new bug was created: [`Two more`c3p0`gadgets to exploit default typing issue \[CVE-2018-7489\]`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1931) which was fixed in version [`2.9.5`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.5). You are using version [`2.9.6`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.6) and you noticed that behaviour changed a little bit since version [`2.9.3`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.3). What does it mean for you? You need to enable `default typing` explicitly because it is not secure. This way:

```
MAPPER.enableDefaultTyping()
```

Check documentation to this method:

> NOTE: use of Default Typing can be a potential security risk if
>   incoming content comes from untrusted sources, and it is recommended
>   that this is either not done, or, if enabled, use setDefaultTyping passing a
>   custom TypeResolverBuilder implementation that white-lists legal types to use.

I suggest to read [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) article and use the latest version of `Jackson` which right now is [`2.9.9`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.9). Read more about [`CVE`](https://cve.mitre.org/) in `Jackson` in [On Jackson CVEs: Don’t Panic — Here is what you need to know](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062) article.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I found the solution I'm going to put it here in a moment. It's not related to the version at all but thank you for pointing this out I'm going to update my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

In case anyone has this issue in the future, in this particular example the Vehicle class would need to be annotated with @JsonTypeInfo like so :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, include = PROPERTY)
interface Vehicle
```

Comment: This annotation does the same what `JsonSubTypes` but with different attributes. We can provide some extra configuration using [enableDefaultTyping](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enableDefaultTyping--) or [enableDefaultTyping(with params)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enableDefaultTyping-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping-com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As-)

Comment: [JsonSubTypes](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html) annotation in documentation says: "Note that just annotating a property or base type with this annotation does NOT enable polymorphic type handling: in addition, JsonTypeInfo or equivalent (such as enabling of so-called "default typing") annotation is needed, and only in such case is subtype information used." Where `so-called "default typing"` is our `enableDefaultTyping` method on `ObjectMapper`. So we have two ways to enable types: by method and annotation.

Comment: My point was if only `registerSubtypes` is used it doesn't work, I also needed to add the annotation

Comment: Basically `JsonTypeInfo` registers the class for polymorphism so it is required when using `registerSubtype` and that's what my problem was

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me. Maybe one difference is I tested it using `Java` not `Kotlin`.

Comment: So I tried using Java and I have the same issue, `@JsonTypeInfo` needs to be there no matter what. No idea why we're having different behaviours. At least it works for me now :) Thanks for your help anyway