# Which version of jackson-databind does not have remote execution vulnerability?

Tags: jackson

I am unable to find online which version of jackson-databind to use with Spring application that doesn't have remote execution vulnerability? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson registerSubtypes not working in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049171/jackson-registersubtypes-not-working-in-kotlin)

Comment: In linked article there is a [On Jackson CVEs: Don’t Panic — Here is what you need to know](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062) which points to [Jackson 2.10 features](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-10-features-cd880674d8a2). It tells that version `2.10` it should be fixed.

Comment: **Major Goals for 2.10**
Looking back, there were 3 major goals for this minor release:
1. "Resolve the growing problem of “endless CVE patches”, a stream of fixes for reported CVEs related to “Polymorphic Deserialization” problem (described in “On Jackson CVEs… ”) that resulted in security tools forcing Jackson upgrades. 2.10 now includes “Safe Default Typing” that is hoped to resolve this problem."

Comment: Thanks! I am glad I could help. Version `2.10.0` is really good! You should definitely upgrade `Jackson` to this version. I added explicit answer just to make it clear for everyone which version starts to handle all vulnerabilities.

Comment: @michalziober don't upvote too many or our accounts could get flagged:p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version [2.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.0) this problem is resolved by adding new set of methods: `activateDefaultTyping` instead of deprecated set of methods `enableDefaultTyping`. Also this problem was one of reasons to why this version was released.

> ##Major Goals for 2.10
> ###Looking back, there were 3 major goals for this minor release:

> 1. Resolve the growing problem of “endless CVE patches”, a
>    > stream of fixes for reported CVEs related to “Polymorphic
>    > Deserialization” problem (described in “[On Jackson CVEs…](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062) ”) that
>    > resulted in security tools forcing Jackson upgrades. 2.10 now includes
>    > “Safe Default Typing” that is hoped to resolve this problem.

More you can find in this article: [Jackson 2.10 features](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-10-features-cd880674d8a2).

Example code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.PolymorphicTypeValidator;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
public class JsonPathApp {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
            .allowIfSubType(MyValue.class)
            .allowIfSubType(ArrayList.class)
            .build();
    
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL).build();
        }
    }
```